# arc4random_uniform not available in Xcode 7.0 beta (7a176x) on OSX 10.10.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, arc4random

I'm trying to use `arc4random_uniform` in the Xcode build mentioned, but it seems to no longer be available:

[image: arc4random_uniform no longer available]

An alt-click on the available functions show that they're declared in stdlib.h, which has them listed as follows:

[image: stdlib.h showing arc4random_uniform defined]

It seems strange that its no longer available. This particular stdlib.h is within the iOS 9.0 simulator directory at `usr/include/stdlib.h` not sure if that helps or not.

I have the latest command line tools installed. Not sure what's going on. Any advice / help / fixes are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Seems to be an Xcode bug, references for which are:

- 22275032
- 22275176

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be still available (I have been using it in 7A176x, but on El Capitan), it is just not shown in the suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I loaded a different project that had it in there already and that didn't raise any issues. Like you said, seems to work, just not in autocomplete. Thanks for taking the time to check.

Comment: @KyleGillen: It looks like a problem in the auto-generated Swift headers (where it also does not appear), so you could file a bug report.

Comment: @MartinR will do. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Actually `arc4random()` is also missing. I assume a problem with the `u_int32_t` type.

Comment: @MartinR &KyleGillen  If you have time to file a bug, feel free to reference my 22275032.

Comment: @MirekE brilliant. Done 22275176